# Python - Recursively create arbitrarily nested dict given three different lists

Tags: python, list, recursion, dictionary, tree

Suppose I am given three lists: a list of roots, a list of children (which can have children), and a list of nodes. On any of the items in these lists, I can call use an attribute .children to get its children.

The goal is to construct an arbitrarily nested dictionary that could look like this:

```
{root_item: {child_item: {child_child_item: [node1, node2]}}}
```

My attempt so far -- in one method, I call a recursive method:

```
structure = {}
for root in list_of_roots:
    structure[root] = self._build_structure(root)

def _build_structure(self, item)
    if item in list_of_nodes:
        return item
    else:
        for child in item.children:
            self._build_structure(child)
```

So, the problem with this is that the recursive method doesn't return any of the intermediate stuff, just the nodes (children without children). I am missing something and need some help figuring out how to go about this.

Please keep in mind that I am new to programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def _build_structure(self, item)
    if item in list_of_nodes:
        return item
    else:
        return [self._build_structure(child) for child in item.children]
```

you need to return your recursive call ... if you need more help you will need to post a minimal example of `list_of_nodes` ....

Comment: This definitely helps, but then structure ends up being a dict where a key is a root and its value is a list of lists without the root's children anywhere. Thank you for your help!

Comment: see the last part of my answer ... we need to actually see some input as well as expected output for that input