# How to create a 3 dimensional dictionary from 3 lists in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pulp

I have 3 lists

```
i = ['a','b','c']
j = ['1','2','3']
l = ['01','02']
```

I want to create a dictionary looking something like this:

```
D = {'a':{'1':{'01':10, '02':100}, {'2':{'01':20,'02':50}}}
```

I want to be able to loop over `i, j` and `l` and do `D[i][j][l]` to get the value associated with it.

```
Ds = {}
l_ = 0
for i_ in range(len(i)):
    j_ = 0
    for j_ in range(len(j)):
        l_ = 0
        for l_ in range(len(l)): 
            Ds[i[i_]] = {j[j_]:{l[l_]:'some value'}}
```

I tried this, but this does not work.

**Extra:**
I am writing a Linear program in `Pulp` and I want to create a dictionary of demand values for a particular sku `i`, in period `j` on line `l` so that I can do `Dijl*Xijtl = some_value` summed over `i`, `j` ,`l` for constraints or something like that. These demand values are constants. This could be cartesian product or comprehension. Is there a function similar to `LpVariable.dicts()`?

Comment: You "dictionary" is not a dictionary, check please

Comment: Are you just trying to initialize a dictionary with myriad "some value"'s or where are those numbers coming from?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cartesian product of a dictionary of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228158/cartesian-product-of-a-dictionary-of-lists)

Comment: Linked wrong dupe: I meant [Python - Recursively create arbitrarily nested dict given three different lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24941765/python-recursively-create-arbitrarily-nested-dict-given-three-different-lists)

Comment: I have a data frame with i, j, l and corresponding "some value". Hope this answers your question. @Nick T

Comment: I don't know what it is called then. I thought it is a nested dictionary. Cartesian product? @Dmitry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using PuLP, you may want to look into pulp's makeDict().

Suppose you have the following:

```
i = ['a', 'b']
j = ['1', '2', '3']
l = ['01', '02']
```

and that for your demand values you have:

```
value_a_1_01 = 10
value_a_1_02 = 20
value_a_2_01 = 30
value_a_2_02 = 40
value_a_3_01 = 50
value_a_3_02 = 60

value_b_1_01 = 70
value_b_1_02 = 80
value_b_2_01 = 90
value_b_2_02 = 100
value_b_3_01 = 110
value_b_3_02 = 120
```

You can then create an array that contains your demand data like this:

```
array = [[{'01': 10, '02': 20}, {'01': 30, '02': 40},
          {'01': 50, '02': 60}],
         [{'01': 70, '02': 80}, {'01': 90, '02': 100},
          {'01': 110, '02': 120}]]
```

and now define your dictionary:

```
D = pulp.makeDict([i, j], array)
```

EDIT: Since the data set up was a bit messy before, setting up the array like this makes it much cleaner (and easier to edit):

```
array = [
         [[10, 20], [30, 40], [50, 60]], 
         [[70, 80], [90, 100], [110, 120]]
        ]
```

Now the parameters for makeDict() should be:

```
 D = pulp.makeDict([i, j, l], array)
```

Comment: I was looking for something similar to `LpVariable.dicts()`. This is perfect. Thank you!

Comment: I'm going to make an edit to this because there is a much cleaner way of using makeDict().

Answer (score 1):

If you want "Cartesian product" of lists, you can use:

```
i = ['a','b','c']
j = ['1','2','3']
l = ['01','02']

Ds = {}

for i_ in i:
    item_i = {}
    for j_ in j:
        item_j = {}
        for l_ in l:
            item_j[l_] = '' # Your value                                                                                                                      
        item_i[j_] = item_j
    Ds[i_] = item_i

print Ds
# {'a': {'1': {'02': '', '01': ''}, '3': {'02': '', '01': ''}, '2': {'02': '', '01': ''}}, 'c': {'1': {'02': '', '01': ''}, '3': {'02': '', '01': ''}, '2': {'02': '', '01': ''}}, 'b': {'1': {'02': '', '01': ''}, '3': {'02': '', '01': ''}, '2': {'02': '', '01': ''}}}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Didn't know it was called Cartesian product.

Answer (score 1):

this is a variant using [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and [`setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
from itertools import product

D = {}
for ii, jj, ll in product(i, j, l):
    D.setdefault(ii, {})
    D[ii].setdefault(jj, {})
    D[ii][jj][ll] = None
```

where i used `None` as placeholder for your value.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this would just be to have a dictionary that is keyed by tuple values i.e

```
D ={}
for i in I:
   for j in J:
      for k in K:
         D[i,j,k] = your value
```

Note in `pulp` it would be more common to donate your sets with a capital letter and iterate with the smaller letter.

Answer (score 0):

I think this reads really nicely as a comprehension:

```
D = {i_: {j_: {l_: "value" for l_ in l} for j_ in j} for i_ in i}
```